# Parse RGB string to array

Tags: php

Is there any build-in PHP function to get the following result?

```
    $rgba = "rgba(246, 24, 35, 0.8)";
    $splittedRgba = splitRGB($rgba);

    $rgb = "rgb(246, 24, 35)";
    $splittedRgb = splitRGB($rgb); // splitRGB is the function I need
    /*
        $splittedRgba['r'] = 246;
        $splittedRgba['g'] = 24;
        $splittedRgba['b'] = 35;
        $splittedRgba['a'] = 0.8;

        $splittedRgb['r'] = 246;
        $splittedRgb['g'] = 24;
        $splittedRgb['b'] = 35;
        $splittedRgb['a'] = 1;
    */
```

Comment: There isn't from an arbitrary string, but preg_match() will do the job with an appropriate regexp

Comment: PHP is a toolbox. it contains screwdrivers, hammers, maybe a measuring tape and a pencil. You're expecting it to contain a fully developed house, complete with plumbing and electrical wiring for **EVERY** possible thing you want it to do. Instead of flailing around looking for a can opener that will cook your thanksgiving dinner and help your kids get into college, you should learn how to use the basic tools PHP does provide to BUILD that all-in-one tool.

Comment: @MarcB - don't forget the double claw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a preg_match, but you can also use the simpler `sscanf` function:

```
$rgba = sscanf("rgba(246, 24, 35, 0.8)", "rgba(%d, %d, %d, %f)");

print_r($rgba);

$rgb = sscanf("rgb(246, 24, 35)", "rgb(%d, %d, %d)");

print_r($rgba);
```

`%d` matches a decimal number, `%f` matches a floating point number.

References:

http://php.net/list

http://php.net/sscanf

Don't expect people to provide you with fully working super functional code. Answers here make clear mistakes you made and should give you an idea helping to solve a more complex problem.

So your part here would be something like:

```
function parseRGBa($rgba) {
    $rgba = trim(str_replace(' ', '', $rgba));
    if (stripos($rgba, 'rgba') !== false) {
        $res = sscanf($rgba, "rgba(%d, %d, %d, %f)");
    }
    else {
        $res = sscanf($rgba, "rgb(%d, %d, %d)");
        $res[] = 1;
    }
    return array_combine(array('r', 'g', 'b', 'a'), $res);
}

print_r(parseRGBa('rgba(1, 2, 3, 0.5)'));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/190808).

Comment: Not working with `$rgb = "rgb(246, 24, 35)";`. I don't know if the string starts with rgb or rgba.

Comment: Sorry, I did expect your transfer knowledge to be able to handle the missing code with your own imagination.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Very nice approach, just made a couple of adjustments in your code. )

Comment: The array code style `[...]` doesn't work in PHP prior to version 5.4, but of course you are welcome to extend my answer, good idea there!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `preg_match_all()` function

```
$rgba = array("r" => 0, "g" => 0, "b" => 0, "a" => 1);
$string = "246, 24, 35, 0.8"; // or "rgba(246, 24, 35, 0.8)"
$i = 0;

preg_match_all('/[0-9.]+/', $string, $color);   
foreach ($rgba as $key => $value) {
  $rgba[$key] = $color[0][$i++] ?: 1;
}

print_r($rgba);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [r] => 246
    [g] => 24
    [b] => 35
    [a] => 0.8
)
```

In case you have this format

```
$string = "246, 24, 35"; // or "rgb(246, 24, 35)"
```

as expected, the output will be

```
Array
(
    [r] => 246
    [g] => 24
    [b] => 35
    [a] => 1
)
```

[Working PHP demo](http://ideone.com/t4Ryvc)