# Use array of keys to access multidimensional array?

Tags: php

For example, if I had this array:

```
$my_array = array('a' => array('b' => 'c'));
```

Is there any way to access it like this:

```
$my_value = access_array($my_array, array('a', 'b'));
// $my_value == 'c'
```

I know I could write this, but I'm curious if something like it exists in PHP already.

Comment: Nope, not a single-shot function. but a short recursive one to write indeed.

Comment: I really wonder how using this function is better than using bracket notation (`$my_array['a']['b']`).

Comment: @raina77ow: I assume because this isn't the real code, but an array of keys is provided by another process. But if the OP indeed intended to use it as-is, you have a good point.

Comment: Here's a nice listing of PHP's array functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 1):

One possible (recursive) approach:

```
function access_array(array $target, array $keys) {
   $target = $target[ array_shift($keys) ];
   return $keys ? access_array($target, $keys) : $target;
}
```

Another possible (iterative) approach:

```
function access_array(array $target, array $keys) {
   foreach ($keys as $k) {
     $target = $target[$k];
   }
   return $target; 
}
```

P.S. I can't really say it better than @MarkB [**did**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746636/parse-rgb-string-to-array/25746712#comment40258125_25746636):

> PHP is a toolbox. it contains screwdrivers, hammers, maybe a measuring
>   tape and a pencil. You're expecting it to contain a fully developed
>   house, complete with plumbing and electrical wiring for EVERY possible
>   thing you want it to do. Instead of flailing around looking for a can
>   opener that will cook your thanksgiving dinner and help your kids get
>   into college, you should learn how to use the basic tools PHP does
>   provide to BUILD that all-in-one tool.

Comment: Or, to put it shorter: batteries _not_ included ))

Comment: I didn't want to reinvent the wheel, so I thought I'd check if it existed. After all, accessing deep stupid nested arrays feels like 90% of what I do when working with PHP. :P

Answer (score 1):

Easy

```
function get_nested_key_val($ary, $keys) {
    foreach($keys as $key)
        $ary = $ary[$key];
    return $ary;
}

$my_array = array('a' => array('b' => 'c'));
print get_nested_key_val($my_array, array('a', 'b'));
```

For functional programming proponents

```
function get_nested_key_val($ary, $keys) {
    return array_reduce($keys, function($a, $k) { return $a[$k]; }, $ary);
}
```